# Class not changing after get request Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble changing the class after making a jquery get request.
code:

```
<script>
      //global variable
      var table = []
      var numberofaccounts = 0
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form1').validate();
        // add numbers to select ids
        $(".select_changer").each(function(){
          numberofaccounts++;
          var new_id = "select_class"+numberofaccounts;
          $(this).addClass(new_id);
        });

        $('#apply_btn').click(function() {
          table = []
          var count = 0;
          var text = "";
          var tracker = 0
          $('#stats_table tr').each(function(){
            count = 0;
            text = "";
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){
              count++;
              if (count == 4) {
                text += $( ".select_class"+ tracker + " option:selected" ).val();
              } else {
                text += " " + $(this).text() + " ";
              }
            })
            table.push(text);
            tracker++;
          });
          $.post("/apply_changes", {"data":  JSON.stringify(table)}, function(data) {
            var res = JSON.parse(data);
            if (res.data == true){
              $('#updated').text("Update Successful").css('color', 'green');
              $.get("/", function( data ) {
                $('#stats_table').load("/ #stats_table");
                numberofaccounts = 0
                $(".select_changer").each(function(){
                  numberofaccounts++;
                  var new_id = "select_class"+numberofaccounts;
                  $(this).addClass(new_id);
                });
              });
            } else {
              $('#updated').text("Update Unsuccessful").css('color', 'red');
            }
          });
        });

      });
    </script>
```

So when the page first loads this method changes the class on dynamically created select elements.

```
$(".select_changer").each(function(){
          numberofaccounts++;
          var new_id = "select_class"+numberofaccounts;
          $(this).addClass(new_id);
        });
```

After I make a post to flask the if the response data is true I go ahead and make a get request to grab the updated items from the db.  I then refresh the table.  This works great if I make one request.  However on the second post nothing happens.  This is because the classes that I modified at the start of the page load no longer exist.  So i added the method above to also trigger after the get response (I also tried at the end of the post response). The problem is that the method doesn't seem to run again.  The classes aren't there and as a result when I go to make another post request it can't find the element.  How do I go about fixing this?
Things to note: The get request is necessary, the ids and classes cannot be statically assigned.

Comment: did you try $.post().done(function(){// do the GET here}) instead of inside the $.post function?

Comment: What is the point of your GET request? You aren't doing anything with the returned data. And I assume you are refreshing the table with `$('#stats_table').load("/ #stats_table");`?

Comment: @gre_gor I'm not doing anything with the data yet and yes that's what I'm refreshing the table with.

Comment: @delueg I'll give that a try as soon as I get home.

Comment: @delueg I'm sorry i just reread your comment, the issue isn't with the get request. I get the data just fine. The issue is with $(". select_changer"') code, which works on page load, but doesn't seem work inside the get request or post request.  Still i'm going to try post.done and see if it calls the script then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign classes before you even refresh your table.

`$('#stats_table').load("/ #stats_table");` is called asynchronously and returns before it even completes.

You need to put you code, for assigning classes, inside the complete callback of your `.load()` call:

```
$('#stats_table').load("/ #stats_table", function() {
    numberofaccounts = 0
    $(".select_changer").each(function(){
        numberofaccounts++;
        var new_id = "select_class"+numberofaccounts;
        $(this).addClass(new_id);
    });
});
```